# Plotting to many coordinate systems in my grid-layout then plotting with seaborn and mathplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, grid-layout

**Multi plot-layout troubles**

Trying to plot 3 graphs next to each other, by using mathplotlib for the grid-layout and Seaborn to plot the graphs. The problem is i get to many plots, 3 perfects once + 3 empty coordinate systems.

**What I tried**

The problem comes from mixing the seaborn plot-lib with the matplotlib.

1. Test: is what is seen in the code example and the picture "My result"
2. Test: if "ax=axarr[x]" is removed from the seaborn plot, the results are switched, so the three top graphs are empty and last three is filled, as expected.

```
fig, axarr = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(20, 6))
sns.catplot(x='weekday', kind='count', palette="ch:.25", data=df_total, ax=axarr[2])
sns.catplot(x='month', kind='count', palette="ch:.25", data=df_total, ax=axarr[1])
sns.catplot(x='year', kind='count', palette="ch:.25", data=df_total, ax=axarr[0])
```

My results:

[image: My result]

What I want to achieve:

[image: Trying to achieve]

Comment: This comes up every week or so, you can search for older questions and answers. In short: catplot does not take an `ax` argument, because it creates its own figure. (Though I would be interested to know *why* so many people try to use catplot with an `ax` argument?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `countplot` rather than `catplot`:

```
n = 365*10
df_total = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range(start='2009/1/1', periods=n, freq='D'),
                        'x':np.random.randn(n)})

df_total = df_total.sample(500)
df_total['weekday'] = df_total['date'].dt.weekday
df_total['month'] = df_total['date'].dt.month
df_total['year'] = df_total['date'].dt.year

#fig, axarr = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(20, 6))
#sns.catplot(x='weekday', kind='count', palette="ch:.25", data=df_total, ax=axarr[2])
#sns.catplot(x='month', kind='count', palette="ch:.25", data=df_total, ax=axarr[1])
#sns.catplot(x='year', kind='count', palette="ch:.25", data=df_total, ax=axarr[0])

fig, axarr = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(12, 4))
sns.countplot(x='weekday', palette="ch:.25", data=df_total, ax=axarr[2])
sns.countplot(x='month', palette="ch:.25", data=df_total, ax=axarr[1])
sns.countplot(x='year', palette="ch:.25", data=df_total, ax=axarr[0])
plt.show()
```

[image]